# Unable to mark a second subscript operator overload as const

Tags: c++, matrix, multidimensional-array

So in my Matrix class I've used some weird syntax in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34461416/operator-overloading-2d-array-c) post in order to use the class as a 2D array. However marking the second overload as const just tells me it expected a ';'.

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

using std::ostream;

struct Matrix {
public:
    
    Matrix(float identity = 0.0f) {
        for (int row = 0; row < 4; ++row)
            for (int column = 0; column < 4; ++column)
                matrix[row][column] = (row == column) ? identity : 0.0f;
    }
    
private:
    enum {
        Rows = 4,
        Columns = 4
    };
    
    float matrix[Rows][Columns];
public:
    float (&operator[](unsigned int index)) [Columns] {
        return matrix[index];
    }

    // won't let me mark it as const
    float (&operator[](unsigned int index)) [Columns] const // "expected a ';'" {
        return matrix[index];
    }
    
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, const Matrix& matrix);
    
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, const Matrix& matrix) {
    for (int row = 0; row < 4; ++row) {
        for (int column = 0; column < 4; ++column) {
            stream << (column == 0 ? '[' : ' ');
            stream << matrix[row][column];
            stream << (column == 3 ? ']' : ' ');
        }
        stream << (row == 3 ? '\0' : '\n');
    }
    
    return stream;
}
```

Is there any way for me to fix this so const Matrix instances can use the overload?

Comment: These aren't function overloads but variable declarations.. or I'm not even sure. It's probably not what you intended to do. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @JHBonarius I just want to be able to use [][] on const Matrix objects. It works for non-const ones, but for const it just throws an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
const float (&operator[](unsigned int index) const) [Columns]
```

You could get this by starting with `operator[](unsigned int index) const`, and then adding the result type around it, if you're into that sort of thing.

But why make life difficult?
Use a type alias.

```
using Row = float[Columns];
Row& operator[](unsigned int index);
const Row& operator[](unsigned int index) const;
```